# How can I know who click Google +1 button?

Tags: google-analytics

I install a Google +1 button in the webpage www.hicalc.com 

I don't want to install google-analytics in the website because of it's a little slow.

How can I know who click Google +1 button ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put your analytics tag just before the closing body tag it won't slow your page so much, without it you won't have the tracking.